# How to ignore validation on Model Property?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

i. e How to apply validation on single property of a model while ignoring other(properties of that model) on if(modelstate.Isvalid){}???
**Model**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace abc.Model
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class check_master
{
    public int MCheck_id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string check_name { get; set; }
    public string field { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> max_length { get; set; }
    public int check_id { get; set; }
}
}
```

**View**

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("addCheck", ""))
  {
  <input type="hidden" id="from" name="from" value="@ViewBag.from" readonly="readonly"  />
   <fieldset>


        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList("check_master", "--select checks--")
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBox("checkName", "")
                @Html.ValidationMessage("check_name")
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</p>
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `[Bind(Exclude = "Property_Name")]`

Comment: can you provide the reference as well?

Answer (score 1):

Why have you decorated other model properties with validation attributes if they should be ignored? That doesn't make any sense and it is not possible.

**Use view models**. Define different view models for the different situations and based on the view model and the situation decorate only the properties you need to be validated. Or even better, don't decorate anything, use [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) to express your validation requirements in a fluent and very powerful manner.

Comment: I decorated only single property, but still my modelstate is not valid

Comment: @Kannas, ah, that's not normal especially if you pass a valid value when invoking the controller action. Any code you would like to share with us? And please be exhaustive: model, controller, view. Provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat old question but I don't believe it had been answered properly. Manipulating bind doesn't alter the manipulation process at all, as the validation takes place before/simultanously to binding.
As in the example above, marking a property as excluded will still generate a false modelstate.isvalid property.

The most recommended way about validation issues seems to be to create dedicated ViewModels as it takes care of a few other issues in the same go that you may or may not be aware of.

The alternative to ViewModels is to manipulate the modelstate object to get to pick and choose(or exclude) the properties to validate like so:

(there's some extra code here to remove magic strings)

```
var modelPropAsString = nameof(yourmodel)+"."+nameof(yourmodel.Id);

        if (ModelState[modelPropAsString ].Errors.SingleOrDefault() != null)
        {
            ModelState[modelPropAsString ].Errors.Clear();
            yourmodel.Id = 0;
        }
```

The above will exlude the Id property from validation. You can turn the code around to exclusively validate the Id property if you wish.